# polygon inside another polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon

I need to make a polygon (y) inside a bigger one (x) as shown in the picture below but need to connect each vertex of x to two adjacent vertices of y:

[image]
How to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, minimum size=8cm, draw=black, shape border rotate=30, name=x] at (6,6) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=5cm, draw=black, shape border rotate=30, name=y] at (6,6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertices of the [`regular polygon` shape](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.regular:polygon) are accessible as the anchors `.corner 1`, `.corner 2`, … which we can use to connect the polygons.

For this, I set the outer seps to zero so that anchor lies in the middle of the line and not at the literal corner tip.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  rp/.style={
    regular polygon, draw, shape border rotate=30, outer sep=+0pt, regular polygon sides={#1}}]
\node[rp=10, minimum size=8cm, name=x] at (6,6) {};
\node[rp= 5, minimum size=5cm, name=y] at (6,6) {};
\draw foreach[
  evaluate={\cornerA=int(2*\c);
            \cornerB=int(\cornerA-1);}] \c in {1,...,5}{
              (x.corner \cornerB) -- (y.corner \c) -- (x.corner \cornerA)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my question clear but I need to connect the existing vertices of x to two adjacent vertices of y (that is, create 10 additional edges). I don't want to change the size of the polygons.

Comment: @Vika I've misread your question completely. I've updated my answer, is this what you wanted? Basically `outer sep = 0pt` and use the `.corner ?` anchors.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!!